# SwiftUI string to formatted date (ISO)

Tags: swift, date, datetime-format

can you please help me with that topic?

from the API i get the following date as a string: 2021-05-21T14:35:15.647+02:00

How can i convert this to a date object, so that i can format it?

I tried it in different ways as subscribed here in stackoverflow or in other tutorials, like this:

```
let date = "2021-05-21T14:35:15.647+02:00"

func formatStringDate(date: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMM d, yyyy")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!)
}

var newDate = formatStringDate(date: date)

print(newDate)
```

or

```
let timestampString = "2018-12-09T11:08:48-05:00"
if let date = isoDateFormatter.date(from: timestampString) {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, dd, yyyy h:mm a"
  let dateFormattedString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  print(dateFormattedString) // December, 09, 2018 11:08 AM
} else {
  print("not a valid date")
}
```

But it´s not working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The first one works for me, the second one works when I replace the line `if let date = isoDateFormatter.date(from: timestampString)` with `if let date = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: timestampString)` Can you explain a bit more about what problem you are having?

Comment: Please consider that `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` formats the string according to the locale settings, the order of the date components is irrelevant. The template `"dMMMMyyyy"` creates the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, i got the following snippet to work:

```
let dateString = "2021-05-21T14:35:15.647+02:00"
let inputFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
inputFormatter.formatOptions = [
  .withFractionalSeconds,
  .withFullDate
]
let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYYY"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))
```

Thanks